# number of tetrahedra in unstructured mesh when edge length is halved

Tags: unstructured-mesh, mesh

For a given 3D domain, two unstructured tetrahedral meshes M_1 and M_2 are generated. The average edge length in M_1 is double the average edge length of M_2.

Are there estimates on the ratio of the number of tetrahedra in both meshes?

Comment: Wouldn't it simply be ~8x?

Comment: @stali Adaptive meshes could have a factor less than that.

Comment: @stali That would be true for hexahedral meshes.

Comment: Why dont you quickly test in Cubit/Gmsh?

Comment: @stali I played around a little with Gmsh, and found that when the average edge length is scaled by a factor of 0.5, the number of tetrahedra increases by a factor of about 6. I don't know under which conditions this holds though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the edge lengths decrease by a factor $k$, the number of tetrahedra will typically increase by between $k^2$ and $k^3$ depending on the adaptivity of the mesh.  A purely uniform mesh will see $k^3$, just as a uniform grid of length $1/n$ has $O(n^3)$ cells.  A highly adaptive mesh with full resolution near a surface will increase by roughly $k^2$, since most of the elements will occur in a band near the surface.  It is also possible to see only a $k$ factor increase if the refinement is near a curve, but this is less common.

Comment: What do you mean by "a purely uniform mesh"? The unit cube subdivided into hexahedra subdivided into tetrahedra?

Comment: "Purely uniform" is perhaps an unfortunate word choice.  By "uniform" I mean a mesh where the edge lengths (and ideally altitudes) of most tetrahedra are within a small constant factor of each other.